# how can I configure yesod with multiple routes pointing to the same entity?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've got a yesod route with two handlers - one for GET and one for PUT:

```
getHotspotR :: Key Hotspot -> Handler Value
getHotspotR i = do
        hotspot <- runDB $ get404 i
        returnJson hotspot

putHotspotR :: Handler ()
putHotspotR = do  
        hotspot <- requireJsonBody
        hid <- runDB $ insert $ hotspot
        sendResponseCreated $ HotspotR hid
```

But I'm not sure what to do for the routing. If I do this:

```
/hotspot/#HotspotId HotspotR GET PUT
```

It complains that the PUT handler has the wrong airity:

```
  Couldn't match expected type `Key Hotspot -> HandlerT App IO res0'
                with actual type `HandlerT App IO ()'
    The function `putHotspotR' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `Handler ()' has none
```

But if I declare another route:

```
/hotspot/#HotspotId HotspotR GET 
/hotspot HotspotR PUT
```

It complains that I've got a duplicate route:

```
/hotspot/#HotspotId HotspotR GET 
/hotspot HotspotR PUT 

Foundation.hs:48:1:
    Multiple declarations of `HotspotR'
    Declared at: Foundation.hs:48:1
                 Foundation.hs:48:1
```

Comment: Http PUT must be [idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) meaning reexecution must not result in duplicate items, which is not your case. If you use PUT for new items, you must give them the same DB key attributes in the table, replacing a possible existing one (SQL insert will trigger an error if the record exists with the same key).

Comment: Also with [Http PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) the URI identifies the resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, these resources are not the same, even though they manipulate entities. HotspotR manipulates a single Hotspot. HotspotsR manipulates the set of Hotspots (e.g. by inserting into that set).

Make sure the routes are named differently.

```
/hotspots/           HotspotsR PUT
/hotspots/#HotspotId HotspotR  GET
```

And then modify your put resource correspondingly.

```
putHotspotsR :: Handler ()
putHotspotsR = do { ... }
```

This will enable you to do the following in the future too.

```
/hotspots/           HotspotsR GET PUT   -- list all hotspots, insert a hotspot
/hotspots/#HotspotId HotspotR  GET PATCH -- Get a hotspot, update a hotspot.
```